# Cannot install google_maps_flutter in MacOS X

Tags: dart, flutter

Cannot install google_maps_flutter in MacOS X, please comment what to do.

```
    $ flutter --version
    Flutter 0.7.3-pre.26 • channel unknown • unknown source
    Framework • revision a9275d2154 (4 hours ago) • 2018-08-29 07:58:11 +0100
    Engine • revision f3ff83a5db
    Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.0.flutter-3e0631761c
```

add a dependency in the pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: "^0.11.3+17"
#  charts_flutter: "^0.4.0"
# map_view: ^0.0.14
# flutter_map: "^0.0.10"
  google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter
```

when update the package, I have got the following error messages.

```
    flutter packages get
    Running "flutter packages get" in coinsbillboard...
    Could not find a file named "packages/google_maps_flutter/pubspec.yaml" in git://github.com/flutter/plugins a9275d2154b16f2bb4ee6474f579d00f2d04c8d6.
    pub get failed (1)
```

Comment: Weird. It worked for me. Are you from China?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

adding the dependency under the section "dev_dependencies", it couldn't be added under the section "dependencies".

```
  dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      google_maps_flutter:
        git: 
          url: git://github.com/gerryhigh/plugins
          path: packages/google_maps_flutter
```